# Img src (\) instead of (/)

Tags: html, css, web

Hi when i try to add image in html and and that image name is "icon.png" is in folder called"img"

i try to use <img src="/img/icon.png" but it doesn't work and when i replace the forward slash with back slash it works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig3RN.png)

Comment: The code is running on a Windows environment, which doesn't recognize `/` as path separators...

Comment: yeah thanks so basically when the file is stored in locally i have to use \ okay got that, but when i use / should be only in url ?